# Take the screenshot at a time to be display the image to image viewer app

Tags: java, android

I have screenshot button and when i take screenshot, image should be stored in the sd card and when i going to see the gallery they display the image.

But, I want to when i take screenshot at a time, to be display in the image viewer app.

**My Code Here:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button captureImage;    
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    captureImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.captureImage);       
    captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
             saveBitmap(bitmap);    
        }

        private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera/"+"MyProfile.JPEG");
              sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,Uri.fromFile(imagePath)));
              FileOutputStream fos;
              try {
                  fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
                  bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                  fos.flush();
                  fos.close();
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screen short saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
        }
        private Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
               rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
               return rootView.getDrawingCache();
        }
    });
}
```

**Manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

> I need out put like this

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you need. You want display result on ImageView? You may do this: `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

Comment: perfectly stored and display in the image to image view. what i need mean when i took the screen short i want to be display the image viewer. image viewer nothing but default mobile image viewer.